# controller#create will not save, @product.save will not work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Basic question, I am trying to save a product to category.  I have my controller#create and form below - thing is my category_id is not saving and I do not know why...

products_controller.rb

```
def create
    @product = Product.new(product_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @product.save
        format.html { redirect_to category_products_path(@product.category), notice: 'Product was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @product }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @product.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for @product, url: category_products_path(@product) do |form| %>
<div class="field">
  <%= form.label :name %>
  <%= form.text_field :name %>
</div>

<div class="actions">
<%= form.submit %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

I also have my models set up accordingly, migrations, schema are all set up correctly.  Anyone see why?

And also here is the console output:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"xpmMl7tIDMTkyFMku7u5UxTvcicZnPwBgMq8xL5qj7aJHRo6iKN2BagkH745gbPap2PUsa2tanYGZru9ZQXimA==", "product"=>{"name"=>"math"}, "commit"=>"Create Product", "category_id"=>"1"}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 29ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid (Validation failed: Category must exist):

app/controllers/products_controller.rb:33:in `block in create'
app/controllers/products_controller.rb:32:in `create'
```

Comment: (1) You should show more of our console output. There should be some more information there. (2) Try `.save!`, which may throw some errors with more information.

Comment: Thanks jvillian!  I guess this is happening because :category_id = '1', is not included in parameters, but I can't figure out why.   I'm using product_params, so don't understand why it isn't included....?  I am thinking my url: in _form.html.erb

Comment: in order to save your product to category, it must be declared as nested form. And the category_id must be in the right position in parameters. https://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#nested-forms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get set the category first from the params.

```
@category = Category.find(params[:category_id])
```

Once that is done, you can associate the product with the category(assuming category has_many products)

```
@product = @category.products.create(product_params)
```

---

Another way of doing it would be(more similar to your approach):-

```
@product = Product.new(product_params)
```

Then attach the `category_id` from the params like this:-

```
@product.category_id = params[:category_id]
```

And then save the product.

Comment: Thank you!  I thought I would have to @product.create first but didn't do the research - thanks for your answer, it saved me time.  Googling this stuff is so hit or miss...:-)

Comment: @Belvin glad it was helpful!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need to assign the category explicitly...

```
def create
  @product = Product.new(product_params)
  @category = Category.find(params[:category_id])
  @product.category = @category
  ...
end
```